# Android-how to count repeated items in a gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i have a gridview of size 7x7 which is inflated with images at random at each item position; choosen from an array of 7 images (7 color ball images).. now i want to count how many times a particular image is shown in the gridview..i.e how many times lets say red ball image is shown in the grid view ..i have also assigned tags and trying to count  the tag value assigned to each view

in my oncreate method i m using this loop... G1 is the gridview object..balloontag[] is used for storing the tag values and toast is just for checking whether i am able to retrieve tag value or not

```
       for( int i=0; i<G1.getCount(); i++)
      {

    ImageView v2= (ImageView)G1.getChildAt(i);
    balloontags[i]=(Integer)v2.getTag();
    Toast.makeText(Cacrballoonclass.this, "lets c tag=" +  

            balloontags[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      } 


             My adapter getview method 



             @Override
     public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) { 

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageView balloonimageview;

        if(arg1==null){
            balloonimageview = new ImageView(ballooncontext);
            balloonimageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(75,75));
            balloonimageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            balloonimageview.setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
        } else {
                balloonimageview = (ImageView)arg1;
                }
        //lets inflate balloon randomly

        int rballoon = new Random().nextInt(ballooninstruct.length);   

   balloonimageview.setImageResource(balloonthumbs[rballoon]);          
       balloonimageview.setTag(balloonthumbs[rballoon]);

        return balloonimageview;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                for(int k=0; k<G1.getChildCount(); k++)
                {
                 ImageView ballcountview = (ImageView)G1.getChildAt(k);
                 Integer b = (Integer)ballcountview.getTag();
                if(balloon_myid==b)
                    {
                        b_count++;

                    }

                } //for loop ends
```

I solved my problem by iterating through each item and retrieving the assigned tag and if matched, count is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is modify the adapter of the Gridview to hold additional information on the Gridview item, like an id / tag, and when i'll need to count items, i'll do it with a HashMap on the data content of the **adapter** and no the Gridview itself.

Comment: ok..i give it a shot ...if you could post an example how to do it with hashmap i would be thank full to you